# Two queries using Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

**Problem:**

Trying to run two MySQLi queries against the database but results always into a failure message.

**Code (PHP):**

```
// Checks whether submit button has been pressed
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // Gets values from form fields
    $email      = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
    $password   = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['password']));

    // Selects e-mail in database
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE email = '{$email}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Error  [' . mysqli_error($link) . ']');

    // Checks whether e-mail exist
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0)
    {
            // Register new user
            $query = "INSERT INTO 
                            userlogin 
                        (username, password, email, regdate)
                            VALUES
                        ('James','{$password}', '{$email}', NOW())
            ";

            // Submit query to database
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Error  [' . mysqli_error($link) . ']');

            // Return success message
            header('Location: index.php?notification=success');
    }
    else
    {
        // Return failure message
        header('Location: index.php?notification=fail');
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: "here is the code, go fix it for me" is not a kind of question warmly welcomed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: why are you use `SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE email = '{$email}'` ? go for `SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE email = '$email'`

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm sorry. In your opinion, how would you recommend to word it?

Comment: @MarkRichards To check first if the e-mail exist, if it doesn't then it should insert it into the table

Comment: @MarkRichards it doesn't matter

Comment: what is the failure error message?

Comment: I would recommend to do a minimal *research* prior asking. To put at least slightest effort instead of just openly asking a community to do your job.

Comment: shouldn't mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0 be mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0?

Comment: @kexxcream can you please give or post error message ??

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have done some research using the manual. Can you please elaborate how you determine that I have not done ANY research prior to posting my question?

Comment: That's simple. There is not a trace of it in your question

Comment: @YourCommonSense So just because you can't see the moon during the day it means it doesn't exist? Right? Your level of logic and deduction is quite baffling. I can't imagine what would happen if you were doing medical research. Next time you release your repulsive attitude try to be motivating and HELP other understand HOW a question should be appropriately written. People are not mind readers here.

Comment: @kexxcream Did you check my answer below?

Comment: @MarkRichards Adding $link and using == instead of != seems to have solved it. Sometimes you stare a bit too long on a problem that it blinds you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't this

```
mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0
```

be

```
mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0
```

Comment: why was this downvoted? He needs to insert in table if email doesn't exist. So shouldn't the condition be this mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I was a bit quick in my logic.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is

```
$email      = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$password   = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['password']));
```

and should be

```
$email      = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$password   = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,stripslashes($_POST['password']));
```

Comment: I am afraid it's not the issue. But you are right about the second parameter.

Comment: 1. it is not an issue. 2. It is not an answer.